# Angular 6 single page template, but with different routes

Tags: php, angular, url-routing, angular-routing

I am currently on a project which develops **Wordpress - Like** website using Angular 6 front-end and PHP 7 and MySQL back-end. All we need to do is, we have different posts on different categories and show them in the website urls like these.

```
www.sample.com/news/news-1
www.sample.com/category1/post1
www.sample.com/category2/post2
```

But our post pages must be identical besides of any of articles or category types and, for that reason, we created a mother component called `template-component`. But the place we got stuck is when routing. All we need to achieve is to make different routes to our pages like upper urls, but keeping our template. Your help or advice are much valuable. (All categories are dynamically generated and can be create/delete or upgrade anytime)